# OfficeJS - Outlook addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am building a outlook look alike window using OfficeJS/HTML. I wanted the auto populate (Address gets populated as in when you type) to be enabled in the To and CC Email address fields
Solution is built on
Office JS API 1.3
Office 365 installed in local machine

Outlook Window using HTML Javascript, Jquery

Any leads on this please.

Comment: A bit confused about your use case, what is this "look alike window"? Are you implementing an add-in taskpane or popping a dialog? We don't have any API that specifically helps with auto populating those fields, but we do have APIs that help with setting the "To" and "Cc" fields: Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync, Office.context.mailbox.item.cc.addAsync

Comment: Did you get to implement this? Which APIs did you use to implement Auto-suggest Emails as you type?